# creating a Javascript-based news ticker

Tags: jquery, settimeout, infinite-loop, ticker

I'm creating a ticker of sorts, and need it to be running until the page is obviously closed or navigated away from.

This script will just be cycling through li (this is what I've got so far):

```
$("li").hide(); //hides all "li" onload
var lis = $("ul").children("li").size(); //counts how many "li"s there are
var count = 0;
while(true)
{
    count++;
    if(count>lis) //checks if count needs to be reset
    count = 1;

    $("li:nth-child(" + count + ")").fadeIn('slow');
    setTimeout('', 4000);
}
```

Obviously the page won't load because of the the infinite loop.  Does anyone have any suggestions about how I should go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ticker = $('ul.ticker');
ticker.children(':first').show().siblings().hide();

setInterval(function() {
    ticker.find(':visible').fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).appendTo(ticker);
        ticker.children(':first').show();
    });
},2000);
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/7uMWF/)

Answer (score 0):

You should have your setTimeout point to the function that you want to have fire each time, and have that function also call setTimeout again.  It's effectively infinite polling, but with the built-in delay.  It also lets you set a flag if you want to break the (i.e. by not calling setTimeout again).

Comment: how should i keep the script running infinitely? because while(true) isnt working

Comment: Or you could use setInterval to continuously call a 'next element'.

Comment: That's what I'm saying.  setTimeout takes a function as its first param. If you have that function do the logic inside your loop (instead of the loop) you just keeep resetting setTimeout forever.  setInterval (as rcravens said) is another means, but in most cases I find setTimeout to be more reliable b/c you don't have to worry about whether your code finishes before the function gets called again.

Answer (score 0):

There is also something else like a jquery plugin ([jQuery webTicker](http://jonmifsud.com/web-tools/jquery-webticker/)) that does all the work for you. For example you can just do an unsorted list

```
<ul id='webticker'>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

use jquery on top of it

```
jQuery('#webticker').webTicker();
```

and this will automatically start your rotating script you will also need some additional CSS which is provided along the plugin itself for styling which can be modified. The script includes and automatic stop function when mouse is on top of the webticker whilst you can have fade in and fade out effects as explained in the [webticker example](http://jonmifsud.com/web-tools/jquery-webticker/) on the download website

Answer (score 0):

To add to Reigel's brilliant answer,

```
var ticker = $('ul.ticker');
ticker.children(':first').show().siblings().hide();

setInterval(function() {
ticker.find(':visible').fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).appendTo(ticker);

    // fadeIn() rather than show() here to create a continuously fading effect.

    ticker.children(':first').fadeIn();
});
},2000);
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you add some text to explain how this adds to Riegel's answer / why it's necessary, etc.?

Comment: Thanks gung. I commented in the code that using fadeIn() instead of show() means text is always fading in and out making it appear smoother.